# Show $e^{-tA}$ is a trace class operator, $t>0$

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, trace, self-adjoint-operators

I have the next definition: $Tr(A)=\sum_n<u_n,Au_n>$, where $A$ is a positive linear operator on $H$ (Hilbert), and $\{u_n\}$ is an orthonormal base of $H$. And an operator is trace class if $Tr(A)<\infty$.

Let $A:D(A)\subset H\to H$ a positive, self-adjoint, densely defined operator in $H$, Hilbert. $A$ only has point spectrum $\sigma (A)=\{ \lambda_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\lambda_k < \lambda_{k+1}$ $\forall k$. $\{u_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is the respective orthonormal base of eigenvectors of $A$.

I know that the trace is independent of the base, its ciclicity, and that $<v,Av>\geq\lambda_1\|v\|$.

I got that $Tr(e^{-tA})=\sum_k e^{-t\lambda_k}$ but I don't know how to show it's finite if is possible.

Any help is regarded.

Comment: if $t=0$, this doesn't seem finite.

Comment: Yes, I know the identity operator is not trace class.
$t>0$

Comment: In order for this to work out you would need some additional assumption about how fast $\lambda_k$ grow with $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the operator
\begin{align}
A = \sum^\infty_{n=1} \log(1+n) |u_n\rangle \langle u_n|
\end{align}
then we see that
\begin{align}
e^{-tA} = \sum^\infty_{n=1}e^{-t \log(1+n)}|u_n\rangle \langle u_n|.
\end{align}

Note that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}(e^{-tA}) = \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{(1+n)^t}.
\end{align}
which does not converge for $t\le 1$.

Comment: Putting $\log(1+\log(1+n))$ instead of $\log(1+n)$ we can even get an example in which there is no convergence for any $t$.

Comment: @Blazej good point.